# Why doesn't my CUDA kernel alter my array?

Tags: cuda, pycuda

I am teaching myself CUDA from the ground up. I made this simple kernel that adds 1 to each of the relevant elements within a 2D array. The elements of the 2D array stem from the red channel of an image (zebra.jpg).

```
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import matplotlib.image as img
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
import numpy as np

my_image = img.imread("zebra.jpg")[:,:,0]
block = (32, 32, 1)
grid = (8, 8)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  width, height = np.int32(my_image.shape)
  im = np.array(my_image)
  print 'original sum: ' + str(np.sum(im))

  # Create the CUDA kernel, and run it.
  mod = SourceModule("""
    __global__ void add1ToEverything(float* r, int w, int h) {
      int rowID = blockDim.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
      int colID = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

      if (rowID > 0 && rowID < h - 2 && colID > 0 && colID < w - 2)
        r[rowID * w + colID] += 1.0;
    }
  """)
  func = mod.get_function('add1ToEverything')

  for i in range(0, 5):
    func(cuda.InOut(im), width, height, block=block, grid=grid)
  print 'new sum: ' + str(np.sum(im))
```

However, then I run this program, I get the following results.

```
original sum: 1828815
new sum: 1828815
```

Why is my original sum identical to my new sum? Shouldn't the new sum be greater?

Here is zebra.jpg.

[image]

Comment: I'm not really sure about pycuda. Do you need to copy out the result from device memory to/back to host memory?

If youw ant to edit the whole image, it is required to set the grid to the image size.
i.e: grid.x = width % block.x ? width/block.x : width/block.x+1

Comment: Thanks! I'm basically trying to figure out how to edit an array and then send it back to the CPU. I wonder why pycuda isn't doing that...

Comment: @DavidFaux: If you use pycuda.driver.InOut(im) it will do the copy to and from the gpu for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your problem is at the line:
`int rowID = blockDim.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;`
it should be:
`int rowID = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;`